# NUMA affinity for Kubernetes --cpu-manager-policy

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes v1.10, i am using --cpu-manager-policy=static. Is there way to control the cores to be allocated from a NUMA socket? If there is two NUMA sockets and there is a DPDK application to be run inside the container, it's expected the cores to be allocated from NUMA socket 1 as PCI device is from NUMA socket-1. how to achieve this with --cpu-manager-policy feature in kubernetes